# SQL - unique users who are visiting for the first time

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, window-functions

Given following table `visitorLog`, write a SQL to find the following by date.

> 1. Total_Visitors
> 2. VisitorGain - compare to previous day
> 3. VisitorLoss - compare to previous day
> 4. Total_New_Visitors - unique users who are visiting for the first time

```
visitorLog : 
*----------------------*
|  Date        Visitor |
*----------------------*
| 01-Jan-2011     V1   |   
| 01-Jan-2011     V2   |           
| 01-Jan-2011     V3   |           
| 02-Jan-2011     V2   |              
| 03-Jan-2011     V2   |          
| 03-Jan-2011     V4   |         
| 03-Jan-2011     V5   |
*----------------------*           

Expected output:
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
|  Date     Total_Visitors VisitorGain VisitorLoss Total_New_Visitors |
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
| 01-Jan-2011      3              3            0            3         |      
| 02-Jan-2011      1              0            2            0         |       
| 03-Jan-2011      3              2            0            2         |
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

Here is my SQL and [**SLQ fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4S4pdpJDR4FRdYx3NuAUgW/1).

```
with cte as
(
    select
        date,
        total_visitors,
        lag(total_visitors) over (order by date) as prev_visitors,
        row_number() over (order by date ) as rnk
    from
    (
        select
            *,
            count(visitor) over (partition by date) as total_visitors
        from visitorLog
    ) val
    group by
        date,
        total_visitors
),
cte2 as
(
  select
    date,
    sum(case when rnk = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_new_visitors
  from
  (
    select 
        date,
        visitor,
        row_number() over (partition BY visitor order by date) as rnk
    from visitorLog
   ) t
  group by
    date

)

select
    c.date,
    sum(total_visitors) as total_visitors,
    sum(
        case
            when rnk = 1 then total_visitors
            when (rnk > 1 and prev_visitors < total_visitors) then (total_visitors - prev_visitors)
        else 
            0
        end
    )visitorGain,

    sum(
        case
            when rnk = 1 then 0
            when prev_visitors > total_visitors then (prev_visitors - total_visitors)
        else
            0
        end
    ) as visitorLoss,
    sum(total_new_visitors) as total_new_visitors  
from cte c
join cte2 c2
on c.date = c2.date
group by
    c.date
order by
    c.date
```

My solution is working as expected but I am wondering if I am missing any any `edge cases` here which may break my logic. any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic does what you want:

```
select date, count(*) as num_visitor,
       greatest(count(*) - lag(count(*)::int, 1, 0) over (order by date), 0) as visitor_gain,
       greatest(lag(count(*)::int, 1, 0) over (order by date) - count(*), 0) as visitor_loss,
       count(*) filter (where seqnum = 1) as num_new_visitors
from (select vl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by visitor order by date) as seqnum
      from visitorLog vl
     ) vl
group by date
order by date
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9403813ed3881f2034a940cc6053f3e2) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions and aggregation:

```
select 
    date,
    count(*) no_visitor,
    count(*) - lag(count(*), 1, 0) over(partition by date) no_visitor_diff,
    count(*) filter(where rn = 1) no_new_visitors
from (  
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by visitor order by date) rn
    from visitorLog
) t
group by date
order by date
```

The subquery ranks the visits of each customer using `row_number()` (the first visit of each customer gets row number `1`). Then, the outer query aggregates by `date`, and uses `lag()` to get the visitor count of the "previous" day.

I don't really see the point to have two distinct columns for the difference of visitors compared to the last day, so this gives you a single column, with a value that's either positive or negative depending whether customers were gained or lost.

If you really want two columns, then:

```
    greatest(count(*) - lag(count(*), 1, 0) over(partition by date), 0) visitor_gain,
    - least(count(*) - lag(count(*), 1, 0) over(partition by date), 0) visitor_loss
```

Comment: I am not getting expected result for `visitorGain` and `visitorLoss`, here is the fiddle  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/afNWbCA2fkBYwZJduHY7No/0